# How to return forwarding references?

Tags: c++, c++11, return, forwarding-reference

**What is the most natural way to return a forward (universal) reference?**

```
struct B{
         template<class Ar> friend
/*   1*/ Ar&& operator<<(Ar&& ar, A const& a){...; return std::forward<Archive>(ar);}
         template<class Ar> friend 
/*OR 2*/ Ar& operator<<(Ar&& ar, A const& a){...; return ar;}
         template<class Ar> friend 
/*OR 3*/ Ar  operator<<(Ar&& ar, A const& a){...; return std::forward<Ar>(ar);}
         template<class Ar> friend 
/*OR 4*/ Ar  operator<<(Ar&& ar, A const& a){...; return ar;}
/*OR 5*/ other??
}
```

The case I have in mind is a stream-like object that is constructed and immediately used. For example:

```
dosomethign( myarchive_type{} << B{} << B{} << other_unrelated_type{} );
```

Comment: Your use of `std::forward` looks legit, but note that in C++, function overloads may not differ only in return type (which your `/*1*/` and `/*2*/` seem to be).

Comment: @VioletGiraffe these are alternative (sloppy notation)

Answer (score 6):

It is very rarely a good idea to return an rvalue reference.  The rare exceptions are cases where you are writing a function logically equivalent to `std::forward`.

The reason why it is a bad idea is that reference lifetime extension is not transitive, and you can easily get dangling references accidentally.

```
const auto& foo = some_operation;
```

if `some_operation` is a prvalue expression, the lifetime of the temporary is extended to that of `foo`.  However, if `some_operation` is instead:

```
foo( some_prvalue_expression )
```

where `foo` takes an rvalue reference and returns it, instead you silently get a dangling reference.

For types that are cheap to move, the solution is simple:

```
struct B{
  template<class Ar> friend
  Ar operator<<(Ar&& ar, A const& a){...; return std::forward<Archive>(ar);}
}
```

This returns by reference if passed an lvalue, but by value if passed an rvalue.

Now reference lifetime extension works correctly.

This requires that your type be cheap-to-move; so

```
myarchive_type{} << B{} << B{} << other_unrelated_type{};
```

results in the `myarchive_type{}` being moved 3 times.

If your type isn't cheap to move, consider simply blocking the rvalue version; the lack of safety makes it not worth it.

For a concrete example, look at this function:

```
template<class C>
struct backwards {
  C c;
  auto begin() const {
    using std::rbegin;
    return rbegin(c);
  }
  auto end() const {
    using std::rend;
    return rend(c);
  }
};
template<class C>
backwards(C&&) -> backwards<C>;
```

(Apologies if I got the deduction guide wrong).

Now we do this:

```
for( auto x : backwards{ std::vector<int>{1,2,3} } ) {
  std::cout << x << ",";
}
```

the `vector` is moved into `backwards`, but if we do this:

```
auto vec = std::vector<int>{1,2,3};
for( auto x : backwards{ vec } ) {
  std::cout << x << ",";
}
```

no copy is made.

Without the "create a copy and return it if we are passed an rvalue", the first for loop above instead has a dangling reference in it.

---

I've seen a few proposals or ideas for proposals to try to generalize reference lifetime extension, or at least provide compilers with hints that the return value of a function depends on the lifetime of the arguments passed to it so that it can generate errors/warnings when you are using dangling reference this way.  None, as far as I know, have made it into a C++ standard.

Until one does, casually returning an rvalue reference is simply too dangerous for my blood.

---

Suppose you consider moving expensive.  Well this works:

```
std::invoke([&](auto&& ar){
  dosomething( ar << << B{} << B{} << other_unrelated_type{} );
}, myarchive_type{} );
```

it takes the temporary `myarchive_type{}` and stores it in an rvalue reference.

Then it passes it to a lambda.  Inside the lambda, the name `ar` is an lvalue.  We proceed to use it safely within the lambda.

Comment: Ok, so for cheap to move you suggest `/*OR 3*/ Ar  operator<<(Ar&& ar, A const& a){...; return std::forward<Ar>(ar);}`. That will always move construct the return value if the passed argument is an rvalue?

Comment: @alfC Yes.  And if not (expected to be) cheap, it isn't a good idea to do it at all; the danger is too high.

Comment: Can you write the example without using the deduction guideline?, I think the example will be clearer for both of us. It looks like the first loop will be `for(auto x : backwards<std::vector<int>>{ std::vector<int>{1,2,3} } ) {`, is it?

Comment: @alf sure.  But the point is that we want to do type deduction using forwarding references.  `T&&` with an lvalue deduces `T` to be an lvalue reference type.  With an rvalue, it deduces `T` to be a non-reference type (and hence `T&&` is an rvalue reference type).  Search for reference collapsing rules and forwarding or perfect forwardimg reference deduction.

Comment: Suppose for a second that I want to avoid the move constructor calls as much as possible in the chained statement (or eliminated completely if possible) and I am not afraid of dangling references (for certain --mis--uses not related to the chained statement). What other option do you recommend? It looks to me that that option would be `# 1`, no?

Comment: @alfC Added a lambda based "safe" version of streaming with a temporary `myarchive_type{}` that is slightly more verbose than just using it directly.  Within the body of the lambda passed to `invoke` the rvalue reference `ar` is an lvalue, and doesn't expire.  So `<<` returning a reference to the `ar` is safe as houses.  If you aren't in [tag:C++17], simply write your own `notstd::invoke`.  The extra verbosity is worth the code being "safe by default"; tracking down dangling references to temporaries is insanely difficult, so making code that just doesn't have that problem is worthwhile.